# Replace string on myBB forum (textare) when key is pressed - jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, replace

I'm trying to do something like.. When pressing CTRL+b it should add [b] and [/b] around the selected text. I can get the selected text by using this Javascript code: [Get the Highlighted/Selected text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5379120/get-the-highlighted-selected-text?answertab=votes#tab-top)

However... When I try something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $('#message').on('keydown',function(e) {
        key = e.which;
        if(e.which == 39){
            str = getSelectionText();
            $("#message").replace(str,"[b]"+str+"[/b]");
        }
    })
});
```

it won't work. It will say "Object [object Object] has no method 'replace'" which is odd, because when I do alert(str); it will display the selected text.

Can anyone tell my why? Key 39 is right arrow key.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By the way. I'm just using 39 (right arrow key) as a test.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a jQuery object, that's why `.replace` wont work. You need to add `.val()` to get the actual value, then you have to set it as well:

```
var value = $("#message").val();
value = value.replace(str,"[b]"+str+"[/b]");
$("#message").val(value);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. I'm getting confused on Javascript and jQuery sometimes!